# Namedpipe hangs when sending large string

Tags: c#, java, named-pipes

I have a c# namedpipe server created like so:

```
 NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(IVConstants.PIPENAME, PipeDirection.InOut);
 pipeServer.WaitForConnection();
 pipeWriter = new StreamWriter(pipeServer);
 pipeWriter.AutoFlush = true;

  try
  {
     pipeWriter.WriteLine("You are Connected!!!");
  }
  catch (IOException e)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("ERROR: {0}", e.Message);
  }
```

Writing out small strings like the one above gives no problem.
However when I start chugging out huge strings e.g 1500 chars, the pipe hangs and stays hung until I kill the client it is trying to send something to. The client is a java app.
I see that is DOES send stuff to the client, after-which the hang happens.

The client is a Java app receiving with this:

```
RandomAccessFile pipe = new RandomAccessFile("\\\\.\\pipe\\mypipe", "rw");

while(true)
{                   
  String received = pipe.readLine();
  processEvent(received);
  System.out.println("Response: " + received );
}
```

The client doesn't throw an exception, and I can see the System.out after the readline().
So what gives?

Comment: Does the client see the entire 1500 character string, or just a part of it?

Comment: The *pipe* can't really hang. Does the client code or the server code hang? If it's the client, that's because you've done a `while(true)` and it's waiting for the next line of data.

Comment: Actually I think it's the client that's hanging
pipe.readLine();

Please see Edit.

Comment: Could you post the server code that writes the strings to the pipe, and maybe the server main loop?

Comment: Does the 1500 character string have a newline in it anywhere? That is, are you calling `WriteLine()` or `Write()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bah! Pure foolishness on my part.
It seems something was hanging in

```
processEvent(received);
```

I thought it was getting to

```
System.out.println("Response: " + received );
```

But it wasn't. processEvent(...) had a duplicate `System.out.println("Response: " + received );` in it, hence my confusion.
It had nothing to do with the namedpipe after-all.

Thanks guys =)

Answer (score 0):

In case this might help anyone, my C# pipe server was hanging because I was trying to send a `char` array. I had to convert it to a string.

This fails:

```
char[] buf = new char[1024];
// (move stuff to buf...)
var pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(...);
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(pipeServer);
writer.WriteLine(buf);    // hangs if char[]
```

This works:

```
string str = "";
for (int i = 0; buf[i] != '\0' && i < buf.Length; i++)
    str = str + Convert.ToChar(buf[i]);
writer.WriteLine(str);
```

I'm new at C#, so there's probably a smarter way of converting to a string.